# change the expiration time of the laravel cached item

Tags: php, laravel, caching

I am working with the Laravel native cache, guiding me from the official documentation, I am using the **add** method to save my data in cache:

```
Cache::add('key', 'value', $seconds);
```

This works correctly when the expiration time is passed as a third parameter as an integer in seconds, according to the documentation I can use the helper `now () -> addMinutes (10)` to change the time in minutes, hours etc. But this does not work for me, it is as if time does not pass. So Laravel stores the data in cache indefinitely, how can I solve this?

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: @Rwd version 5.8

Answer (score 2):

If you are working with Laravel 5.8,try using

```
Cache::put('key', 'value', now()->addMinutes(10));
```

that would work fine.

Comment: So `now()->addMinutes(10)` it only works with the put method? I really needed to use the `add` method, since according to the documentation there is an important difference between the two and that is what I need to use

Comment: in the documentation itself they used add with seconds only, while put is used with seconds and minutes, try converting to seconds. i never face that problem before because i use it only as described in the documentation.

Comment: I just tried the method to get out of doubt and it doesn't work either, I did the test with `now()->addMinutes(30)`

Comment: that is really weird this behavior should only occur when the storage time is not specified.Make sure that Carbon dependency is implemented correctly and call it using Carbon::now()->addMinutes(30).